# How to implement a context controllable Swift Codable Encode function?

Tags: swift, codable

I'm trying to implement an encoder for a Codable struct that I can control by passing in a context which determines which fields I would add to the output JSON. But I can't figure out a nice way.

For example say I have the following:

```
import Foundation

struct MyStruct: Encodable {
    var a:Int = 0
    var b:Int = 0

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case a
        case b
    }

    enum Context {
        case summary, full
    }

    // I can write something like this
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(a, forKey: .a)
        try container.encode(b, forKey: .b)
    }

    // ...but I want to write is something like this
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder, withContextcontext: Context ) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(a, forKey: .a)

        if context == .full
        {
            try container.encode(b, forKey: .b)
        }
    }

}

var myObject = MyStruct()
myObject.a = 10
myObject.b = 5

let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
do {
    let jsonData = try jsonEncoder.encode(myObject)
    // let jsonData = try jsonEncode.encode(myObject, withContext:.full)
    let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!
    print(jsonString)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Are there any nice solutions that would give the same effect as my imaginary encode(:WithContext) functionality?

I have one solution that I'm not that keen about is adding the context variable to the struct and setting it before calling encode():

```
struct MyStruct: Encodable {
    var a:Int = 0
    var b:Int = 0
    var context = .full

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case a
        case b
    }

    enum Context {
        case summary, full
    }



    // But I want to write is something like this
    func encode(to encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(a, forKey: .a)

        if context == .full
        {
            try container.encode(b, forKey: .b)
        }
    }

}

var myObject = MyStruct()
myObject.a = 10
myObject.b = 5
myObject.context = .summary

let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
do {
    let jsonData = try jsonEncoder.encode(myObject)
    let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!
    print(jsonString)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Not sure I want to add this Context variable to every stuct I have. Is there more elegant ways?

Comment: Why isn't what you've written a "nice solution"? To put it another way: why is what you've written "imaginary"? The whole point of writing your own `encode(to)` is that you can do whatever you want. What actual problem are you having?

Comment: Because swift expects encode just to have a single argument (to encoder: Encoder)? I'm not sure how to pass in the context variable.

Comment: Oh! I see. Well, there is no need to "pass in" the context; the context simply needs to live at a high enough level of scope that `encode(to:)` can just see it when it is called. And it does. So again I ask, what's the problem? Basically your (new) code compiles just fine.

Comment: By the way, it's also common to handle similar problems using classes and inheritance (I am not saying it's the best solution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to pass some context to `Encoder`, you can always use [Encoder.userInfo](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/encoder/2894907-userinfo):

> Any contextual information set by the user for encoding.

Example:

```
struct MyStruct: Encodable {
    var a:Int = 0
    var b:Int = 0

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case a
        case b
    }

    enum Context {
        case summary, full

        static let encodingKey = CodingUserInfoKey(rawValue: "my_struct_context")!
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(a, forKey: .a)

        if (encoder.userInfo[Context.encodingKey] as? Context) == .full {
            try container.encode(b, forKey: .b)
        }
    }
}

var myObject = MyStruct()
myObject.a = 10
myObject.b = 5

let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
jsonEncoder.userInfo = [
    MyStruct.Context.encodingKey: MyStruct.Context.summary
]

do {
    let jsonData = try jsonEncoder.encode(myObject)
    let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!
    print(jsonString)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Cool, I'd forgotten all about that! (If I ever even knew about it!!!) Still, in this particular case I don't understand what the OP's difficulty is supposed to be; the context is in scope.

Comment: It wasn’t a difficulty as such more a search for better solutions - if they exist. I didn’t want to add a context variable to all my classes, and just wanted to ask the community if there was a better way that I wasn’t aware of - such as that suggested.

Comment: @PhilipPegden Cool, if this is what you were looking for you should accept this answer.